# Imbalanced target (over and under sampling)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, resampling

I'm working on a machine-learning project and my target is quite imbalanced (only 9% positive), so I need to resample the data to ensure that the model doesn't get biased toward the majority class, right?

At the same time, I want to evaluate many models and take three to use VotingClassifier or stacking. So what I want to ask is, do I need to sample my data every time I'll evaluate a new model? I mean, the resampling should be inside the "for" loop?

In my script, I preprocessed the data using ColumnTransform, resampled the dataset, and then split the data into train and test. After all that, evaluated the models. Below is what it looks like right now.

```
# Define resampling
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.1)
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)

# Pipeline
sampling_pipe = imbPipeline(steps=[
        ("over", over),
        ("under", under)])

# Apply the sampling technique
X_sampled, y_sampled = sampling_pipe.fit_resample(X_transformed, y)

seed = 42
# Split data into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_sampled, y_sampled, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

# Create a DataFrame to store the results
cross_val_results = pd.DataFrame({"Classifier": classifiers.keys(), "Mean CV score": np.empty(len(classifiers)), "Running time (s)": np.empty(len(classifiers))})

folds = 10
i = 0
print("Running time: ")
print(30*"-")
for key, classifier in classifiers.items():
    
    # Start timer
    t0 = time.time()
    
    # 10 fold cross-validation
    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    cross_val_scores = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=cv)
    cross_val_results.iloc[i, 1] = cross_val_scores.mean()
    
    # Stop timer
    t1 = time.time()
    cross_val_results.iloc[i, 2] = np.round(t1 - t0, 2)
    
    # Print running time
    print(f"{key}:", cross_val_results.iloc[i, 2], "s")
    
    # Next row
    i += 1
```

Is that right? Or the `fit_resample` part should be inside the loop?